# Windows api using jna: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java, jna, advapi32

I need to use [RegLoadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724889(v=vs.85).aspx) function in my java code by using [jna](https://github.com/twall/jna), but I'm getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'RegLoadKey': The specified procedure could not be found.
>   Blockquote

RegLoadKey syntax

```
LONG WINAPI RegLoadKey(
  _In_      HKEY hKey,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
  _In_      LPCTSTR lpFile
);
```

my code:
Advapi32.java

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Advapi32 extends StdCallLibrary
{
    long RegLoadKey(HKEY hKey, String lpSubKey,String lpFile);
}
```

apiTest.java

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY;
public class apiTest
{
       public static void main (String [] args)
       {

          Advapi32 lib2 = (Advapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32", Advapi32.class);
          HKEY key1 = new HKEY();
          String filePath = "C:\\tmp\\software";
          String regName = "loadedRegKey";
          long test = lib2.RegLoadKey(key1, regName, filePath);
       }
```

I think there are several problems with my code. I'm new to windows api and jna.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that an Advapi32 encapsulation is already part of JNA?
Have a look [here](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.java). I just saw that your method `RegLoadKey` is not yet added there. So add it and submit that change to the jna guys. Afterwards you can use it like this (pseudo code):

```
public class RegistryRead{

 private Advapi32 api = null;

 public RegistryRead(){
    this.api = Advapi32.INSTANCE;
 }

 public void read() {
    long winapi = this.api.RegLoadKey(HKEY hkey, String subkey, String file);
    ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `Advapi32` library mapping [that comes with JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.java#L50), you'll see that the library instantiation includes some [options](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIOptions.java#L21) to the load method.   Among other things, these load options automatically map things like `RegLoadKey` to `RegLoadKeyW`, which is the real name of the function you're trying to link to.

Answer (score -1):

It is a typical for JNA developing error. Just add before using it.

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path","PATH_TO_LIBRARY_JNA");
```

PATH_TO_LIBRARY_JNA - absolute path to jna lib

Comment: advapi32 will almost never need a custom load path.